# Custom rendering of a "repeated" field from Symfony 2 in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I just started using Twig and I'm trying to build a registration form. To add a password/re-enter password field I use the "repeated" filetype:

```
->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type' => 'password',
    'invalid_message' => 'Passwords have to be equal.',
    'first_name'      => 'Password',
    'second_name'     => 'Re-enter password',
));
```

which works as intended. The problem I have however is that I want to add some custom classes etc. to my form. So my template looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ path('register') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
    <div class="form-field">
        {{ form_label(form.username, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-label'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-input'} }) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    <div class="form-field">
        {{ form_label(form.email, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-label'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-input'} }) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
    <div class="form-field">
        {{ form_label(form.password, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-label'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.password, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-input'} }) }}
    </div>

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

    <input type="submit" class="contact-submit" />
</form>
```

this works fine for everything except for the password part. I want to render both fields seperately there, now they are just both rendered in the same div.

How do I fix this? Is there a way to select the seperate fields in Twig? Or am I just doing something wrong because I encounter this problem in the first place.

Comment: Here's the answer you're looking for (using Symfony 2.2) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16119798/2056878

Comment: Here's the answer for your question (using Symfony 2.2) :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16119798/2056878

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After a random guess I solved my own problem. I'll post it here so others who might come to this question by searching also know the answer:

```
{% for passwordField in form.password %}
    <div class="form-field">
        {{ form_label(passwordField, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-label'} }) }}
        {{ form_widget(passwordField, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-input'} }) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for coming back and answering your own question!

Answer (score 27):

If you want to seperate both passwords field from a repeated method in your twig template you just have to call back their respective names like:

```
{{ form_label(form.password.pass, "Password :") }}
{{ form_widget(form.password.pass) }}

{{ form_label(form.password.confirm, "Confirm :") }}
{{ form_widget(form.password.confirm) }}
```

And of course in your function:

```
/..
->add('password', 'repeated', array(
'first_name' => 'pass',
'second_name' => 'confirm',
'type' => 'password'
))
```

Regards.

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```
....
{{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}
<div class="form-field">
    {{ form_label(form.password.first, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-label'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-input'} }) }}
</div>

{{ form_errors(form.password.second) }}
<div class="form-field">
    {{ form_label(form.password.second, null, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-label'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.password.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-input'} }) }}
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Users Bundle they use the password.first and password.second, even better try using your profiler to see what variables comes from the view and controllers ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have application wide classes for your labels and inputs, you can customize how labels and widgets are rendered. Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

If you look at this file:

```
vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig
```

You can see the defaults for all widgets. To achieve specifically what you need, you could override generic_label block to add form-label class:

```
{% block generic_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required %}
        {# We add form-label class in the next line! #}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required form-label'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

And widget_attributes block to add form-input class:

```
{% block widget_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    {# We add form-input class in the next line! #}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-input'}) %}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %}{{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}" {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock widget_attributes %}
```

With these two templates all your inputs should render with the classes you need, without having to repeat the 'attr' parameters all over your forms.

I haven't tried it, but this should take care of the repeated field problem. Even if it didn't, you could create a repeated_widget and/or repeated_row template to customize how the repeated widget renders, thus fixing that widget for all the forms that use it.