# Symfony 2 + Bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

How can I adapt my form to implement bootstrap ?

My function for create form is:

```
private function createCreateForm(User $entity)
{

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ))
    ->add('username')
    ->add('email')
    ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
       'first_name'  => 'password',
       'second_name' => 'confirm',
       'type'        => 'password',
    ))
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'))
    ->getForm();
    return $form;
}
```

My views is

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Imię oraz nazwisko'} }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.password, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'} }) }}
```

It is working for username but not for the password, some sugestion ? How can i create our own form ?

My bootstrap:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-md-3 control-label">NAME</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-actions fluid">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn blue">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn default">Anuluj</button>                              
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mopa Bootstrapbundle https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle

In your controller:

```
 $this->createForm(
      MyFormType(),
      $entity,
      array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-horizontal'))
 );
```

Comment: ok but this is class for all field, what i must do if i need some class for one field and other for the rest ? What can I do to add clase for create form ?

Comment: You're correct, If you install mopaBootstrapBundle all form fields will transformed in bootstrap form fields.
Have a look in the cookbook @ Symfony and read Customize Form Rendering: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: i can't use moba because i have template :) i must implement it but i don't know how ;/ The main problem is the form. e.g how can i replace my example above to symfony code.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the Form Customization section from the Symfony Cookbook. Read "Form theming in Twig", that's the answer to your question or do I misunderstand you? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig

Comment: ok thx but i have small problem with the password field. Symfony form has a some widget for it ? i mean that i need use validation password (2 field to check that user gave the same password in two places)

Comment: On stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675329/custom-rendering-of-a-repeated-field-from-symfony-2-in-twig